# flooring cover near shower

Tags: shower, floor, waterproofing, fiberglass

I have a fiberglass shower, and the image below shows a slight tilt in the floor covering; likely due to water. Can I use something like a [Silicone tape](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08ZJNPTCT)?
I want to make sure that the water doesn't get into flooring woods.

Any recommendation or off-the-shelf product that I can buy?

[image]

Comment: Is the subfloor underneath rising up, or is the floor covering just lifting off of the subfloor?  Depending on the answer, there will be different potential solutions.

Comment: The floor under seems solid; I don't feel any softness. I believe it is only the floor covering. Honestly, I don't want to remove the floor covering to check subfloor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as the floor is sound solid, in other words no sign of wetness or dry rot etc., yes you can.

From what I read your concern is not to get water in that space where the linoleum meets the tub.

Before caulking it, it won't hurt to put some sort of cement such as Liquid Nails™ or what have you first. Somehow get it under the lip of the linoleum to help secure it to the floor.

Let the cement sit for few a minutes so it get nice and tacky, it helps the linoleum adhere without rising up again.

This will also help a lot with caulking it.  It will look better and work better and makes everything go smoothly  for you.

Comment: Thank you. I will look into liquid nail.